# Fire function only on startup of an Ionic-Android App

Tags: android, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I need to check if some information is available from a REST api every time the app starts. So far i've tryed this:

in app.component.ts

```
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    initializeApp();
}

initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.diarios.initializeDiarios(); // this checks if there's new info to download
    }
  }
```

The problem is that this approach makes my method fire every time i load a new page, not only at start as i need. The idea is to check if there's new info in my service, if true, then update some stuff, if false, then don't check until the next time the user opens the App.

Comment: It called only once on app start. Are you refreshing the page?

Comment: When i go from one page to another, the function fires again, and that shouldn't happen.. i don't know how to avoid that, i need that function to only fire once, and during startup, not every time i load a page or navigate through my app